# Why does the type of my DataSource seem to change when I call .OrderBy on it before passing it to a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, linq, bindinglist

I'm having a problem I hope someone can help me with.

I have a class, EmployeeList that inherits from:

```
public class MultipleSortableBindingListView<T> : BindingList<T>, IBindingListView
```

I fill the EmployeeList, and set a BindingSource.DataSource equal to it:

```
EmployeeListBindingSource.DataSource = lstEmployees.OrderBy(t=>t.LastName)
   .ThenBy(t=>t.FirstName);
```

Then, when I reference the DataSource, it is no longer of type EmployeeList.

Basically, I need to cast back to `EmployeeList` after the `OrderBy` is performed.

Comment: Correct, the expression returns type `IEnumerable<T>`, in your case `IEnumerable<Employee>`. You could possibly pass the result to a new instance of your destination type as a constructor argument: `var yourList = new EmployeeList(sortedList);`

Comment: OrderBy doesn't sort your list.  It creates an IEnumerable<T> which the DataSource property setter most likely converts into some flavor of IList.  Sort your items before you add them to EmployeeList and you should have a better chance of getting it back as an EmployeeList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to do something like:

```
var newlist = new EmployeeList(lstEmployees.OrderBy(t=>t.LastName).ThenBy(t=>t.FirstName));
```

However, since EmployeeList derives from a class with the name `MultipleSortableBindingListView` one would suspect that it has it's own means of  setting the sort order, without have to resort to using LINQ.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I ended up changing Employee List to inherit from BindingList since I was not longer using those sort properties.  Then when I set my datasource I had `new employeelist(emplist.orderby().thenby().ToList());`     I added a constructor to employeelist to handle this: `public EmployeeList(IList<Employee> collection)
            :base(collection)
        {
        }`

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this recently. (I think)

What happens when you call those LINQ methods (.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)) on your EmployeeList, It changes the type of EmployeeList to something like 'IOrderedList'.

James Curran has provided a viable workaround to this convention.